# How do I put a view over a full-screen movie triggered from inside a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Inside of an app I'm building, there is a UIWebView that we use to give the user a 'limited' browser.  Amongst other things that can be done with this browser is visiting some sites that can play videos in full screen mode.

Unfortunately, full screen mode interferes with other things the app does.  Most notably, an inactivity warning that should present over everything else is hidden away behind the full screen video.

Also, videos can sometimes continue playback AFTER the UIWebView is destroyed -- but I imagine that's a seperate question.

How do I force my text on top of the full screen video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: You can't.  This is not possible.